# MySql Looping Each Row with calculation

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to update each row in MySQL table using stored procedure but the problem is my code below is not working:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATESCORE()
BEGIN
LOOP
   UPDATE scoretable SET `final_average` = (`term1_result` + `term2_result`) / 2;
END LOOP 

END 

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can you post your scoretable table structure?

Comment: this all INT(11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Remove the Loop From your procedure as Update work for all row if you don't have  Where clause. Also Update query work by default in safe update mode so you need to set that to false.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

and then there is no error when you run that procedure also.
Your Update query would:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATESCORE()
BEGIN
UPDATE scoretable SET `final_average` = (`term1_result` + `term2_result`);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: this not working !.. it won't update all the row inside my table,example i have 20 rows it only updated 5 rows

Comment: it is not an error, it is working but problem is only 5 rows is affected every time i call the procedure not all rows i have 20 rows

Comment: i think because of the NULL value it wont calculate if is null

Comment: @Greigh Can you check with without NULL value. If you want to add NULL value for all data  then just set that value to NULL

Answer (score 0):

Remove loop, update works on each row if there is no where clause.